# How to stop viewpager page scrolling when viewpager item is touched?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using a circular indicator view pager with a timer to scroll the pages automatically.

What i want is when a viewpager item is in touch mode then the timer should pause and the page shouldn't be changed during the touch period. How to do that??

```
mPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // Auto start of viewpager
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (currentPage == slidingImageList.size()) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        };
        Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(Update);
            }
        }, 4000, 4000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a OnPageChangeListener.

onPageScrollStateChanged will tell you when the state which you can use to cancel/restart any animation logic, e.g. cancel when DRAGGING, start when IDLE.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageScrollStateChanged(int)